# Butterknife - Generated code is unable to import the package correctly (error: package <my-end-package> does not exist)

Tags: android, butterknife

I have an Activity in a package like:

```
 com.example.ui.Auth
```

I've also added the initialization in this Activity's onCreate

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

The property of this activity is bound as:

```
@BindView(R.id.loginEt) EditText loginEt;
```

The weird is that I could use successfully it before for a Activity at the package a level before ( com.exemplo.ui ). So, I have it installed correctly.

Comment: Ok, I just found what was going on... Butterknife recognized Auth as an Class. I shouldn't create a package starting with UPPERCASE letter. Once I rename the package to "auth", or "userAuth" everything works perfectly.